# save(commit=False) returns: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a pretty normal model:

```
class Nonce(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(_('key'), max_length=36, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    token = models.ForeignKey('Token')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), blank=False, default='1970-01-01 00:00:00')
    date_consumed = models.DateTimeField(_('date consumed'), blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.IPAddressField(_('IP address'), blank=False, default='0.0.0.0')
    consumed_by = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.key
```

Many, many of these will be created and I only need to retain a fraction of these that are actually 'consumed' (used).  Also, it is not evident from the model, but these will expire in 1 hour.

So, in the interest of not cluttering up my DB with a bunch of old nonces and to spare the application the work of periodically (frequently) deleting expired ones, I thought it best to just store them in RAM until they are consumed (if ever).

So, I've forked my code and I thought I'd just replace my code where I save() the objects that are created with save(commit=False), then store the object into RAM (Memcached). Later if a particular nonce is consumed, I'll then save() properly, otherwise, the object will just expire and be purged via Memcache.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error: `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'` from Django at the line nonce.save(commit=False).  Why?

I'm using Django 1.4.5 and Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django's `Model` class doesn't have defined the `save` method that way. That is for `ModelForm`s. The method signature for normal `Model`'s `save` method is this one:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
```

You'll have to try another approach.

[This is the dev's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) for Model's `save` method and [this one is the version 1.4's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Though may have been a bit dissapointing for you :-/

Comment: Only a little, I think the solution is to just not call save() at all, until I really want it in the DB. Simple!